# Keeping float left div on the same line

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
.holder{
width:3in; 
height:4in; 
background:aqua;

}
.orangeBox{
float:left;
background:orange;
width:1in;
height:1.5in;
}
.yellowBox{
float:left;
background:yellow;
width:1in;
height:1in;
}
</style>
<div class="holder">
<div class="orangeBox">R</div>
<div class="yellowBox">1</div>
<div class="yellowBox">2</div>
<div class="yellowBox">3</div>
<div class="yellowBox">4</div>
<div class="yellowBox">5</div>
<div class="yellowBox">6</div>
<div class="yellowBox">7</div>
<div class="yellowBox">8</div>
<div class="yellowBox">9</div>
<div class="yellowBox">10</div>
<div class="yellowBox">11</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the individual boxes float left (which they're doing) but also to stay on the same line.
In the example here I want box 5 to NOT appear under box R, but rather to automatically wrap to the next full line.

I know this can be achieved via float:right, but that would reverse all the numbers, making everything backwards.

https://jsfiddle.net/o4eem3za/

Comment: Maybe instead of float, you could achieve the layout you're looking for using display inline-block?

Comment: I'm confused - where do you want to see the teal background - only at the very end? Under the R? Beside the R under boxes 1 and 2?

Comment: It should look the same as if you 'float: right' both boxes. Only with number in the correct order.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/o4eem3za/3/
Maybe if you made a quick example of how you wanted it to look in the end, it would be easier to help you

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve there, but only with floats.

Comment: May I ask why it has to be floats?

Comment: I'm using this code in conjunction with MPDF which doesn't support inline-block. Only floats.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear every other element after the 6th element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/t4ntxbkg/)

```
.yellowBox:nth-child(2n + 6) {
    clear: left;
}
```

---

Alternatively, depending on the desired results, you could also just clear the 6th element as well:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/8L7wuaty/)

```
.yellowBox:nth-child(6) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: I can probably adapt this to what I need.
The only issue I can see is the quantities will be dynamic (not always 6), so it could end up looking weird.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just make both boxes orange and yellow same height?

Right now you have orangebox 1.5in and yellowbox 1in heigh.  Set 1.5 for yellowbox also and it will fix your issue.

```
.yellowBox{
   float:left;
   background:yellow;
   width:1in;
   height:1.5in; /* changed this from 1in to 1.5in */
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Munja/o4eem3za/1/

Comment: This is a simplified example. In reality the boxes will be lots of different sizes.

Comment: @Robbie Can't you put every n elements in 1 row? For e.g every 3 children? Or that might be a problem for your desired structure?

Comment: That wouldn't really be possible either, unfortunately. It'll give a different quantity each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a grid pattern, where you have distinct rows, I'd recommend display:table and display:table-cell. (EDIT: discard the display:table stuff, if you're floating R right - unnecessary)

```
<style>
.holder{
width:3in; 
height:4in; 
background:aqua;

}
.orangeBox{
float:right;
background:orange;
width:1in;
height:1.5in;

margin-bottom:.5in;
}
.yellowBox{
float:left;
background:yellow;
width:1in;
height:1in;

}
</style>
<div class="holder">
<div class="orangeBox">R</div>
<div class="yellowBox">1</div>
<div class="yellowBox">2</div>
<div class="yellowBox">3</div>
<div class="yellowBox">4</div>
<div class="yellowBox">5</div>
<div class="yellowBox">6</div>
<div class="yellowBox">7</div>
<div class="yellowBox">8</div>
<div class="yellowBox">9</div>
<div class="yellowBox">10</div>
<div class="yellowBox">11</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: This still uses floats, but it leverages the special display attributes of table cells. Change the width of the .holder to 4 and you will see it functions as you'd expect.

EDIT v2: Changed orangeBox to float right, added .5 margin to bottom, removed display:table stuff (unnecessary if floating per poster's comment)

Comment: This is actually the reverse. I was looking for orange on the right.

Comment: Nevermind - I see in another answer that your heights will vary.  Will the yellow box heights always be the same, or will they all be different?

Answer (score 0):

With display: inline-block you can achieve it

https://jsfiddle.net/o4eem3za/4/

```
 display:inline-block
```